# Background Location Management on Android

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager

Porting our location based game to Android.

We rely on updating user location when the app is in the background. What's the best way to accomplish this on the Android side while mitigating battery impact?

We don't need high-frequency updates, even 20 minute cadence is acceptable.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a [Background Service](http://android.kgmoney.net/2010/05/08/creating-a-simple-android-service-for-background-processing/) in order to accomplish what you want.

Inside that **Background Service** you will need to use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and request for Location Updates.

The function that request for Location Updates takes parameters for the fixes intervals as shown below:

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

you will use the minTime parameter to choose the interval between the fixes:

**minTime** :  *the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.*